# Pandas dataframe to set all columns to be character length fixed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which column names are fixed width of 15. And its elements length different, depends on the data type.

**Original**

```
Name           ,Date           ,Time           ,TST Num        ,Dept/Dest      ,Tst Level      ,AAS            
AAAAAA         ,18/12/2007     ,07:57:40,AAA101         ,AAAABBBB       ,220,320
BBBBBB         ,18/12/2007     ,12:34:06,AAA112         ,XXXXYYYY       ,210,320
```

I will use Pandas to work on it. And the final output should look like:

**Final**

```
Name           ,Date           ,Time           ,TST Num        ,Dept/Dest      ,Tst Level      ,AAS            
AAAAAA         ,18/12/2007     ,07:57:40       ,AAA101         ,AAAABBBB       ,220            ,320
BBBBBB         ,18/12/2007     ,12:34:06       ,AAA112         ,XXXXYYYY       ,210            ,320
```

I can convert each column like:

```
df = df.astype(str)
df['Time           '] = df['Time           '].apply('{:15s}'.format)
```

But I can't do in this way:

```
all_columns = list(df)
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].apply('{:15s}'.format)
```

Is there any way I can do it without a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [applymap?](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)
`df.applymap(('{:15s}'.format)`